# Typeclass declaration type mismatch

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make my `Cell` type a member of the `Show` typeclass. The `show a` line is problematic. How do I make sure that the `a` is a `Char` in that show case? I was hoping the ordering of the statements would just let fallthrough handle it, but that doesn't do it.

```
data Cell = Solid | Blank | Char

instance Show (Cell) where
    show Solid = "X"
    show Blank  = "_";
    show a = [a]

main = print $ show Solid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data Cell = Solid | Blank | Char
```

This is a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), which means `Solid`, `Blank`, and `Char` are constructor names, not types. For example, `Char :: Cell`.

I suspect what you meant was something such as this:

```
data CellType = CellConstructor Char

instance Show CellType where
  show (CellConstructor c) = [c]
```

Examples:

- `CellConstructor 'X' :: CellType`
- `CellConstructor '_' :: CellType`
- `CellConstructor 'a' :: CellType`

It is customary to give the type and constructor the same name if there is only one constructor.

```
data Cell = Cell Char
```

If there is only one constructor with only one field then it is customary to use a newtype.

```
newtype Cell = Cell Char
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't make sure that `a` is a value of type `Char` because that simply can't be the case. `a` will always be a value of type `Cell`, specifically it will be the value `Char` (which has no relation to the type `Char`).

What you seem to want is to have `Cell`'s third constructor contain a value of type `Char`. To do that your constructor needs a parameter:

```
data Cell = Solid | Blank | CharCell Char

instance Show (Cell) where
    show Solid = "X"
    show Blank  = "_"
    show (CharCell a) = [a]
```

The `CharCell a` case matches if the constructor `CharCell` has been used and `a` will be the value used as `CharCell`'s parameter (and thus have type `Char` as that is `CharCell`'s parameter type).

Answer (score 1):

`Char` here is not the type `Char`; it is a new data constructor named `Char`. If you want `Cell` to be `Solid`, `Blank`, or a value of type `Char`, you need

```
data Cell = Solid | Blank | Char Char

instance Show Cel where
    show Solid = "X"
    show Blank = "_"
    show (Char c) = [c]
```

Some examples:

```
> show Solid
"X"
> show Blank
"_"
> show (Char '4')
"4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the definition of the typeclass `Show`, mainly at the `show` function:

```
class Show a where
    show      :: a   -> String
```

Now, does your instance for your `Cell` type satisfy it? The first case, `show Solid = "X"` does - `Solid` is `Cell` and `"X"` is a String. The same goes for the second case. But what is the third case? You defined it as `show a = [a]` so the type signature is `Cell -> [Cell]` and `[Cell]` is not a `String`. Therefore you get a type mismatch.